# NGINX - location {} slug with different root domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, nginx, reverse-proxy

I currently have a `.conf`in my `etc/nginx/sites-available` with a bunch of location entries. Some of those location entries are setup as reverse proxy's to specific ports. However, I'm having trouble adding a location entry that just points at a directory.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;
root /var/www/html;
charset utf-8;

access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain.com-access.log combined;
error_log /var/log/nginx/sub.domain.com.log error;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem;

location /site1 {
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:7777;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /site2 {
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /site3 {
            root /opt/site3;
            index index.html;
            allow all;
}
```

}

Right now, I'm having trouble getting `sub.domain.com/site3` to serve the content of `/opt/site3`.

Any help on how to correctly use `location {}` entries side by side with proxy reverse would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try and visit that domain?  Do you see any error messages?  Does it do nothing?  We need more info.

Comment: I get `404 Not Found` when I try accessing the /site3 slug. I've also double checked that `index.html` is sitting in `/var/www/html/site3`.

Comment: Have you confirmed what path is being tried **on disk** by checking the NGINX error logs themselves?

Comment: It was pointing to `/opt/site3/site3` looking for an `index.html` file there instead of `/opt/site3/`. Fixed it by pointing the root to `/opt/` on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to use `root` with a sublocation will mean that it's going to try `$root$uri`, which in your case becomes `/opt/site3/site3`.

You can do what you did and use `root` so that the root directory is a folder *before* the folder you are trying to access.  However, you don't *need* to do this.

Try using `alias /opt/site3;` instead; this *should* work and access the correct location provided you set the index field, and if necessary have a `try_files` in that location block as well.

Comment: Also realized I could use `alias` with `location {}` instead of `root` and it'll point to `/opt/site3/` instead of `/opt/site3/site3/`.